# This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory

Tags: sql-server, docker, sql-server-2019, sql-server-linux

I am accessing SQL Server using a Docker container, and have done using this step:

1. `docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password@123" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" -p 1433:1433 -v mssqlserver_volume:/var/opt/mssql --name mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU15-ubuntu-20.04`
   (I use this code in cmd to create a container)
2. Continue command docker ps
3. The container able to created but the status only showed running for 1 seconds, then keep exited. The logs keeps shows this when I try to run the container:

   > sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory.
   > /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory.

Now I not able to proceed with command this code

```
docker exec -it mssql /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Password@123
```

since the container keeps showing "exited".

The methods have I tried is to restart and also swapping memory from wsl1 to wsl2 but it didn't solve my problem

Kindly need assistance to solve this problem.

[Logs for SQL Server container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBHPn.png)

[The command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtXje.png)

Comment: You should look for the ERRORLOG file. You might find some more interesting information.

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server 2000????

Comment: So if you go to Docker Desktop > Settings > Resources, how much of your computer's memory have you allocated to Docker? That amount is shared amongst all of your Docker containers, including the Docker core container.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - too little RAM was given to Docker and the container. 2 GB not a lot of RAM for a database server. Database servers are fast because they cache data and indexes aggressively. The requirement [is documented too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver16#system) - SQL Server for Linux requires at least 2GB RAM

Comment: BTW both [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/8.0/en/system-prereqs-reference.html) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/supported-open-source/postgresql/installing/requirements/) require 2GB RAM.